# Apache Kerberos Authentication with LDAP Authorization

Tags: apache, ldap, authorization, kerberos

I am stuck with this problem:
I configured apache 2.4 on a SLES15 machine with kerberos authentication. So far, so good. Works. Now I like to authorize agains a LDAP group, which becomes a bit confusing:

- The REALM in the kerberos ticket is: myuser@MY.COMPANY.COM
- This REALM cannot be found in the LDAP directory. The sAMAccountName is just myuser. The UPN of the user is myuser@DIFFERENT.REALM

My apache configuration looks like this:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/protected">
    Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    LogLevel debug
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Login"
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
    KrbAuthRealms MY.COMPANY.COM
    Krb5KeyTab /etc/apache2/keytab/my.keytab
    KrbSaveCredentials Off
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName
    AuthLDAPCompareAsUser on
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://myldapserver/OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=binduser,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    Require ldap-filter "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=myuser)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com))"
```

Whatever I try, it doesn't work. In the debug log I see this:

```
[Wed Dec 27 17:09:03.539584 2023] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 55004] mod_authnz_ldap.c(1331): [client 10.200.xxx.xxx:14134] AH01741: auth_ldap authorise: User DN not found with filter (&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=myuser@MY.COMPANY.COM)): User not found
[Wed Dec 27 17:09:03.539588 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 55004] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 10.200.xxx.xxx:14134] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-filter "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=myuser)(memberOf=CN=mygroup,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com))": denied
```

I even wrote a little python program which checks my filter against the LDAP system. There the user is found with exactly the same filter.

I tried almost everything: changed filters several times, changes AuthLDAPURL, simplified things....

Any help is really appreciated!

Regards
Marco

Answer (score 0):

First, switch from mod_auth_kerb (which is ancient) to [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) (which is not ancient).

With mod_auth_gssapi, enable `GssapiLocalName On` to have it translate principal names to local OS account names. (By default it's a 1:1 translation that just strips the system default realm.)

(As far as I know, mod_auth_kerb does not have an equivalent option.)